# Where can I find the flight path data for the Russian spy plane that flew over the US on 9 Aug 2017?

Tags: military, online-tracking, flight-tracking

Multiple news outlets are reporting that a Russian spy plane, a Tupolev Tu-154M, flew past various locations in the U.S.

[Politico is reporting](http://www.politico.com/story/2017/08/09/russia-military-spy-plane-dc-241455) that the plane was seen on a flight-tracking website in Washington D.C., Bedminster, NJ, and Dayton, OH.

Is there a way (maybe on the flight-tracking website Politico mentions) that I can look up historical data on this flight to see when it was in each place and what its flight path was?

Comment: Without knowing departure or arrival airports and times... FlightRadar24 has a [playback feature](https://www.flightradar24.com/2017-08-09/01:15/108x/38.91,-77.04/13).

Comment: @abelenky: The details of the observation equipment are actually specified in the treaty, and every airplane must pass certification. All sensors used must be commercially available to every signatory. There will also be an official representative of the observed party on board. (The treaty even allows the observed party to choose whether the observing party is allowed to bring their own plane or must use one provided by the observed party). They might be secret from the general public, but not from the signatories of the treaty. I.e. Russia knows exactly what is in the US plane and vice versa

Comment: More details on the treaty here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_on_Open_Skies

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's on [flightradar24.com blog](https://blog.flightradar24.com/blog/recent-interest-tracking-russian-treaty-on-open-skies-observation-flights/):

[image]

> RF-85655’s Open Skies flights over the United States since the beginning of 2017

Here you can see [more details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeYRP.jpg) over Washington.

Two of the recent routes [are here](https://www.flightradar24.com/data/aircraft/rf-85655). One of them flying as low as 3,800 feet.

[image]

Comment: I'd have thrown a T-n-G on 19 at KDCA into there just to trip people up, haha.